# Do large XML file impact speed?

Tags: xml, performance, odoo, odoo-9

Do large XML file impact speed? I have issue with speed of odoo/openerp. after some research with my code, I got that python function that does take time to load including DB communication. Before going to work on XML side. I want to confirm that.

Do large XML files impact the speed?

Should I make separate file for each view?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you program is reading an XML file (or any other file) then it is highly likely that the speed of the program will be affected by the size of the file.

But it's very likely that the relationship is linear (time is proportional to file size) which means that splitting the file into smaller files isn't going to make it faster. In some cases (if you deal with the files one at a time) splitting it might give you a memory saving, but not a time saving.